# Implementing Okta - Angular SPA + SpringBoot + Oauth2

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, okta

hope my question finds you well.

I need to implement OKTA as part of a corporate initiative and I am looking for some general guidance regarding my current situation.

I already have two set of productive Oauth2 implementations (using spring-security-oauth2), actually, with two different versions of SpringBoot (1.X and 2.X). Authentication is delegated to a corporate Active Directory using a Spring LdapAuthenticationProvider as part of the authentication stage. Login is accomplished by the oauth server with an html template using Spring MVC. Authorities and User Detail are implemented by a custom user and authorization legacy model that is stored in a Oracle Database and is retrieved via jdbc.
On the front I have multiple Angular Clients (AngularJs and Angular) each one with its own Springboot microservice on the back where each one of them execute token introspection on the Oauth server.
The current Oauth flow type is Implicit (I am aware that is has been deprecated even Spring Security Oauth as a spring Proyect)
So, I have been catching up with Oauth (I have attached an image with the steps that my Apps currently do regarding security, of course with some level of abstraction) and reading a little bit of OIDC that as far as understood is a thin layer that works over oauth dealing with User's identity.

The actual question is, what would be the best approach to connect with OKTA without too much disruption. I didn't get yet to the technical point where may be having different versions of Spring will force me to go in one particular way perhaps. Will be something that is as simple as coding an extra Authentication Provider within each Oauth WebSecurityConfigurer for example? Would it be  healthier to upgrade SpringFramework version of all applications and from there on use the latest starters (I am aware that there is an okta one), specially the ones in 1.X. Regarding the diagram I have attached, where does Okta takes place?

I would appreciate any guidance please.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okta will replace the lower three (3) boxes in your picture: Authorization server, Active Directory and Login dialog. Also, it will replace a bit of Database too (lines 10 and 11).

Here is what I recommend:

1. Start with this: Oauth2 and OIDC in plain English (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0)
2. Try out: https://www.oauth.com/playground/
3. Setup a free developer account on Okta and try an OIDC example.

In terms of "minimizing disruption":

- Since migration to Okta is certain, you need migrate users and their profile from AD and DB to Okta.
- If the implementation on Client and Resource server is standard, the change would be minimal (with some addition of reading oidc/user info claims).

Comment: just one more thing, what about Spring Authorities, that will also need to go to Okta?

Comment: I have less experience on Spring, but assuming this is about returning User profiles and roles/groups. If yes, then those come from Okta too. Once in your developer account, you will see where they reside.